# Messages on iPhone, iPad and Macbook. One persons messages not on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

I have an iPhone, iPad and Macbook and have the messages set up for all and it works great and everything goes to all devices, except for messages from and to one contact. Messages to him and from him only show up on the iPhone and Macbook but don't show up on my iPad.

Did I do something weird or what can it be?

Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Messages syncing can be finicky. Go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive and verify that your iPad is configured to use all the same addresses that your iPhone and Mac are using.

It is also helpful to make certain that all devices have the same "Start new conversations from" setting. I recommend setting them to start from your phone number, as that's where other are likely to message you. Otherwise you end up with multiple conversation threads with the same person.